# Lodash: Pick list of values from object into array with guaranteed order

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I have an object which looks like:

```
const myObject = {
   foo: '000',
   bar: '123',
   baz: '456'
};
```

I would like to put a subset of `myObject`'s property values into an array. I need to preserve ordering.

A manual solution would look like:

```
const values = [myObject.foo, myObject.baz];
```

One attempt might look like:

```
const values = _.values(_.pick(myObject, ['foo', 'baz']));
```

This solution isn't correct because `pick` creates a new object. Calling `_.values` on the new object removes the ordering specified in the picked array.

Is there a simple way of going about doing this?

Comment: As of ES6 the order should at least be predictable. Numbers sorted first, then string-keys in original order. I tested _.pick, and the new object seems to follow the order of the supplied array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`_.at()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#at) in a similar way to `_.pick()` to get an array:

```js
const myObject = {
   foo: '000',
   bar: '123',
   baz: '456'
};

const array = _.at(myObject, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in vanilla JS:

```js
const myObject = {
   foo: '000',
   bar: '123',
   baz: '456'
};

const array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].map((key) => myObject[key]);

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```